# SysInternal's WinObj device listing mechanism

Tags: windows, operating-system, device-driver, systems-programming

SysInternals's WinObj can list all device objects.

I wonder how it can list the devices.

Is there any open source we can read?(or a code snippet)

What is the most significant function I should know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WinObj uses the NT system calls `NtOpenDirectoryObject` and `NtQueryDirectoryObject`. There is no driver or kernel code needed.  You won't see the imports because these NT functions are loaded via `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`.

You don't have to enumerate the entire object namespace.  If you're interested in the device objects call `NtOpenDirectoryObject` with `"\Device"`, then call `NtQueryDirectoryObject` on the returned handle.

Answer (score 1):

According to [SysInternals' web page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657):

> The native NT API provides routines
>   that allow user-mode programs to
>   browse the namespace and query the
>   status of objects located there, but
>   the interfaces are undocumented.

I've tried looking at WinObj's import table (`dumpbin /imports winobj.exe`) but there are no obvious suspects :-(

Comment: the reason is that winobj spawn a driver called winobj.sys and it responsible to query the devices. it is done in kernel mode.

Comment: @Nuno_147: I can find no evidence that is true. Since you posted that more than 10 years ago, maybe it was true then but not now, although I'm sceptical it was true even then. I'm wondering if you were getting WinObj confused with Process Explorer, which indeed installs a `procexp.sys` driver to get more info on processes. I suspect the actual reason why the APIs it uses aren't visible in the import table, is because it is loading them dynamically using GetProcAddress

Answer (score 1):

As per the [answer from user1575778](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806915) you can use `NtOpenDirectoryObject` and `NtQueryDirectoryObject` (which from user mode are identical to `ZwOpenDirectoryObject` and `ZwQueryDirectoryObject` respectively) to list the objects inside the object manager namespace.

Have a look at `objmgr.hpp` of [NT Objects aka ntobjx](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntobjx/), in particular at the class `NtObjMgr::Directory` (or `DirectoryT`). It provides the same functionality nicely wrapped into a C++ class. The whole utility is open source under a liberal license (dual-licensed due to WTL-use: MIT and MS-PL), so bits and pieces can be reused however you please, provided you comply with the license terms.

But here's a simple C++ code example catering *just* your use case:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <winternl.h>

NTSTATUS (NTAPI* NtOpenDirectoryObject)(PHANDLE, ACCESS_MASK, POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);
NTSTATUS (NTAPI* NtQueryDirectoryObject)(HANDLE, PVOID, ULONG, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, PULONG, PULONG);
VOID (NTAPI* RtlInitUnicodeString_)(PUNICODE_STRING, PCWSTR);
NTSTATUS (NTAPI* NtClose_)(HANDLE);

#define DIRECTORY_QUERY                 (0x0001)
#define DIRECTORY_TRAVERSE              (0x0002)

typedef struct _OBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION {
    UNICODE_STRING Name;
    UNICODE_STRING TypeName;
} OBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION, *POBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION;

#ifndef STATUS_SUCCESS
#define STATUS_SUCCESS                   ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L) // ntsubauth
#endif // STATUS_SUCCESS
#ifndef STATUS_MORE_ENTRIES
#define STATUS_MORE_ENTRIES              ((NTSTATUS)0x00000105L)
#endif // STATUS_MORE_ENTRIES
#ifndef STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES
#define STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES           ((NTSTATUS)0x8000001AL)
#endif // STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES

int PrintDevices()
{
    NTSTATUS ntStatus;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
    UNICODE_STRING objname;
    HANDLE hDeviceDir = NULL;
    RtlInitUnicodeString_(&objname, L"\\Device");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa, &objname, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ntStatus = NtOpenDirectoryObject(&hDeviceDir, DIRECTORY_QUERY | DIRECTORY_TRAVERSE, &oa);
    if(NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
    {
        size_t const bufSize = 0x10000;
        BYTE buf[bufSize] = {0};
        ULONG start = 0, idx = 0, bytes;
        BOOLEAN restart = TRUE;
        for(;;)
        {
            ntStatus = NtQueryDirectoryObject(hDeviceDir, PBYTE(buf), bufSize, FALSE, restart, &idx, &bytes);
            if(NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
            {
                POBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION const pdilist = reinterpret_cast<POBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION>(PBYTE(buf));
                for(ULONG i = 0; i < idx - start; i++)
                {
                    if(0 == wcsncmp(pdilist[i].TypeName.Buffer, L"Device", pdilist[i].TypeName.Length / sizeof(WCHAR)))
                    {
                        _tprintf(_T("%s\n"), pdilist[i].Name.Buffer);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(STATUS_MORE_ENTRIES == ntStatus)
            {
                start = idx;
                restart = FALSE;
                continue;
            }
            if((STATUS_SUCCESS == ntStatus) || (STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES == ntStatus))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        (void)NtClose_(hDeviceDir);
        return 0;
    }
    _tprintf(_T("Failed NtOpenDirectoryObject with 0x%08X"), ntStatus);
    return 1;
}

int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR** /*argv*/)
{
    HMODULE hNtDll = ::GetModuleHandle(_T("ntdll.dll"));
    *(FARPROC*)&NtOpenDirectoryObject = ::GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtOpenDirectoryObject");
    *(FARPROC*)&NtQueryDirectoryObject = ::GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtQueryDirectoryObject");
    *(FARPROC*)&RtlInitUnicodeString_ = ::GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "RtlInitUnicodeString");
    *(FARPROC*)&NtClose_ = ::GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtClose");
    if (!NtOpenDirectoryObject || !NtQueryDirectoryObject || !RtlInitUnicodeString_ || !NtClose_)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Failed to retrieve ntdll.dll function pointers\n"));
        return 1;
    }
    return PrintDevices();
}
```

**Some remarks:** This will *not* delve into subdirectories, it will *not* list any types other than `Device` and it will not resolve symbolic links, if any. For any of those features, please look at the aforementioned utility's source code and adjust as needed. `winternl.h` should be available in any recent Windows SDK.

The functions `RtlInitUnicodeString_` and `NtClose_` have a trailing underscore to avoid clashes with these native API functions, which are declared in `winternl.h`, but use `__declspec(dllimport)`.

**Disclosure:** I am the author of ntobjx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NtOpenDirectoryObject and NtQueryDirectoryObject to enumarate the objects list in a given directory.

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of the object namespace, you must use the Windows NT Undocumented API. That is also used by the WinObj as it is described [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2014/02/05/creating-a-winobj-like-tool/) that how WinOBj getting the all results..and for those who are saying that we need a driver to do this please, read these lines on given page.

> "One obvious way is to use a driver – in kernel mode everything is accessible – so the client app can get the required information by communicating with its own driver. WinObj does not use a driver, however (this is one reason it’s able to execute without admin privileges, although with admin privileges it shows all objects as opposed to partial results)."

Answer (score -1):

You can start with SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList and use other related functions to enumerate all the devices.  This stuff is painful to use.

Comment: SetupAPI (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList etc.) enumerates device nodes (the stuff you see in the Device Manager), not device objects (those created by IoCreateDevice).